# How to specify geolocation feature in Tizen config.xml file?

Tags: xml, config, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am developing Weather "webapp" for tizen which also uses geolocation feature to search for the weather for particular coordinates. Though my app is working fine in web simulator. But in order to run this app safe and sound in device or emulator we have to provide some features or privileges in config.xml

I had tried with this as provided in their developer [documentation](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.0/?topic=%2Forg.tizen.web.appprogramming%2Fhtml%2Fapp_dev_process%2Fediting_tizen.htm)

But didn't got anything working, Tried adding features in XML which is

```
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location.gps"/>
```

How can figure out this thing in safe and sound way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/location"/>
```

feature setting is only to notify store what are you using.

Comment: It's not working does i have to add anything more as i had removed previous "location.gps" feature and added the privilege you had given

Comment: Could you add more info about what is not working? Do you have any logs in console? Are there all location objects returned from JS properly?

Comment: Thanks man for your answer but i had posted same question in their (tizen) forum and they are saying that we have to inject location through EventInjector. As i think currently there emulator doesn't support geolocation feature. Also in your answer it is used to provide privilege not for the accessing location, for location we have to use feature <feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/location.gps"/>

Comment: feature is information for Tizen store - your app will not display for devices without GPS. privilege will allow your app to run certain device stuff - location in your case.
To test properly your app, you have to use Event Injector for sure. It will help you with GPS, but with other sensors, like gyro, accelerometer and so on. I don't have access to emulator now, but you should try to right click on emulator and you will find EventInjector somewhere

Comment: Okay gotcha. Is EventInjector is also available from emulator? I thought we can try hand on eventinjector through SDK only.

Comment: In emulator from SDK 2.3 you have to right-click and choose Control Panel. One of the options is Event Injector with Location.